# How to convert Dictionary to List with mixing of values and keys?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have some dictionary. Let it be:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary< string, List<MyClass>>();
```

I need to convert it to list of object that contains property from key and value.
I did it with foreach loop in the next way:

```
var list = new List<dynamic>();
foreach (var key in dictionary.Keys)
{
    var values = dictionary[key];

    foreach (var obj in values)
    {
        list.Add(new
        {
            obj.Property0,
            obj.Property1,
            obj.Property2,
            ...
            key
        }
        );
    }
}
```

It works, but looks rudely as for me. Is it possible to do it more gracefully with LINQ?

Comment: Can you show the code for `MyClass`.  I assume it implements `IEnumerable` since you do a `foreach` on `values`.

Comment: Indeed - a short but *complete* example would make this a lot easier to help you.

Comment: @juharr thank you, I have missed that it is list of MyClass.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that with a `SelectMany`.

```
var list = dictionary.SelectMany(
        kvp => kvp.Value, 
        (kvp,obj) => new {obj.Property0, obj.Property1, obj.Property2, kvp.Key})
    .ToList();
```

Or in query snytax

```
var list = (from kvp in dictionary
           from obj in kvp.Value
           select new {obj.Property0, obj.Property1, obj.Property2, kvp.Key})
    .ToList();
```

Note this results in a list of an anonymous class.  If you really want `dynamic` you'll need to do a `Cast<dynamic>()` before the `ToList()`.  Also if you want the last property of the anonymous class to be `key` instead of `Key` you'll need to do `key = kvp.Key`.

Comment: And slap a `.ToList()` at the end if you actually want a list.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Very true, fixed.

Comment: Great solution. It is what I am looking. Thanks!